# Authentication for appcfg.py download_data

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I use appcfg.py download_data?

I always get user / password prompts (instead of browser based OAuth2 authentication) which fail.

I received an email from Google, that the "Sign-in attempt prevented" because the app does not meet modern security standards.

Calling with option --oauth2 does not help

Comment: Same Problem...

appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --url=http://diarybooker-com.appspot.com/process/remote_api --application=diarybooker-com --filename=config-20160125-1602.yml --oauth2_access_token=xxxx --email=johnvdenley@googlemail.com

gives me:
    raise ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError(ADC_HELP_MSG)
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available.

Comment: Do you have `login: admin` in the handler in app.yaml?  If so, remove that.